# Copy form elements by field ID instead of by field name

Tags: javascript

I found a file called copyShipping.js that allows me to copy form elements from one form to another by the click of a checkbox.  However, it copies by name of each field rather than ID.  Below is the code.  How do I get it to copy by ID? I know there's a getElementByID on Javascript but I don't know how to implement it.  Ideally I would just like the code changed for me.  Thanks.

```
function eCart_copyBillingToShipping(cb){
if(cb.checked){ // Only copy when the checkbox is checked.
    var theForm = cb.form;
    // The number of elements must match in billingFields and shippingFields. The type of input element must also match between the arrays.
    var billingFields = new Array('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'fax', 'street1', 'street2', 'city', 'state_province', 'StateOther', 'other_state_province', 'postcode', 'other_postcode', 'country');
    var shippingFields = new Array('shipping_firstname', 'shipping_lastname', 'shipping_email', 'shipping_phone', 'shipping_fax', 'shipping_street1', 'shipping_street2', 'shipping_city', 'shipping_state_province', 'ShippingStateOther', 'other_shipping_state_province', 'shipping_postcode', 'other_shipping_postcode', 'shipping_country');

    for(var i=0;i<billingFields.length;i++){
        var billingObj = theForm.elements[billingFields[i]];
        var shippingObj = theForm.elements[shippingFields[i]];
        if(billingObj && shippingObj){
            if(billingObj.tagName){ // non-radio groups
                var tagName = billingObj.tagName.toLowerCase();
                if(tagName == 'select'){
                    shippingObj.selectedIndex = billingObj.selectedIndex;
                }
                else if((billingObj.type && shippingObj.type ) && (billingObj.type == 'checkbox' || billingObj.type == 'radio')){
                    shippingObj.checked = billingObj.checked;
                }
                else{ // textareas and other inputs
                    shippingObj.value = billingObj.value;
                }                   
            }
            else if(billingObj.length){ // radio group
                for(var r=0;r<billingObj.length;r++){
                    shippingObj[r].checked = billingObj[r].checked;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) What are your target browsers? In browser versions younger than 10 years, you do not have to change anything as per [W3C DOM Level 2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-40002357) and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/infrastructure.html#htmlformcontrolscollection) the collections work with both names and IDs. Also, for a radiobutton and checkbox group it does not make sense to copy individual controls by ID.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to access the elements using Id. Also it is recommended to have id and name same.

Try this.

```
function eCart_copyBillingToShipping(cb){
if(cb.checked){ // Only copy when the checkbox is checked.
    var theForm = cb.form;
    // The number of elements must match in billingFields and shippingFields. The type of input element must also match between the arrays.
    var billingFields = new Array('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'fax', 'street1', 'street2', 'city', 'state_province', 'StateOther', 'other_state_province', 'postcode', 'other_postcode', 'country');
    var shippingFields = new Array('shipping_firstname', 'shipping_lastname', 'shipping_email', 'shipping_phone', 'shipping_fax', 'shipping_street1', 'shipping_street2', 'shipping_city', 'shipping_state_province', 'ShippingStateOther', 'other_shipping_state_province', 'shipping_postcode', 'other_shipping_postcode', 'shipping_country');

    for(var i=0;i<billingFields.length;i++){
        //assuming that now array contains id (not name)
        var billingObj = theForm.getElementById(billingFields[i]);
        var shippingObj = theForm.getElementById(shippingFields[i]);
        if(billingObj && shippingObj){
            if(billingObj.tagName){ // non-radio groups
                var tagName = billingObj.tagName.toLowerCase();
                if(tagName == 'select'){
                    shippingObj.selectedIndex = billingObj.selectedIndex;
                }
                else if((billingObj.type && shippingObj.type ) && (billingObj.type == 'checkbox' || billingObj.type == 'radio')){
                    shippingObj.checked = billingObj.checked;
                }
                else{ // textareas and other inputs
                    shippingObj.value = billingObj.value;
                }                   
            }
            else if(billingObj.length){ // radio group
                for(var r=0;r<billingObj.length;r++){
                    shippingObj[r].checked = billingObj[r].checked;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How did you get that idea? First of all, referring by ID is not backwards-compatible. Second, it might not be possible to use the same value for `name` and `id` attribute because a) IDs must be unique, control names do not, and b) not all characters that are allowed in a control name are also allowed in an ID.

Comment: First, referring by ID breaks in browsers like IE7 which very few people use now. Value of Name and Id are not required to be same however developers try to keep it same (Ofcourse if possible) just as good coding practice. It helps in readability and maintainability. You said you don't know how to implement getElementById so I modified the code with that. If you do not want to use that then try to use eval('theForm.'+shippingFields[i])

Comment: I wonder where you get your information from. 1. Provided Valid markup, `document.getElementById(…)` does *not* break in IE7. It has been supported since IE/MSHTML 5.0. 2. `eval()` is evil[tm]. 3. Reference by plain property name is proprietary, and deprecated because it is error-prone. The safe and standards-compliant way to refer to a form control by name is using collections: `theForm.elements[shippingFields[i]]`.